# mongoDB optimal schema design

Tags: mongodb

The page has 2 links, View Articles and View My Favourites Articles. I am wondering where should I capture the favorite article ObjectID in a MongoDB schema. In User Schemas or Article Schema when users clicked on the View My Favourite link? Here is my MongoDB schema for both User and Article. Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate for comments. Thanks

```
//Article Schema
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: "Title is required",
        trim: true,
        },
    bodytext:{
        type: String,
        required: "Body is required"
    },
    category:{type:ObjectID,ref:"Category"},
    favourite:[{type:ObjectID,ref:"User"}],
    date: {
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now 
    },    
},
{ timestamps: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);


//User Schema
   const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      displayname: {type: String, trim: true},
      favourite:[{type:ObjectID,ref:"Article"}],
    },{ timestamps: true });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```